# Using jQuery with Razor in ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my view I have this code

```
<a href="#" class="bt_on" title="ON">ON</a>
<script type="text/javascript">switchOnOff()</script>
```

And I have this jQuery code in a file named "on-off-button.js"

```
$(function switchOnOff () {
  $("a.bt_off").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("bt_on");
  });
  $("a.bt_on").click(function () {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass("bt_off");
  });
});
```

And to wire all this I put this in my layout file

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/on-off_button.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now When I load my page, I het an exception from Microsoft JScript saying that the value of the property  is Null or Not Defined, not a Function object

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that function switchOnOff() is visible to code in your view? You create it and pass to jquery. I don't think it is visible to your view. Also I don't understand why are you calling it yourself when you already add it to jquery's document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

Your View cant see the .js file for some reason.

Try this :

```
<script src="../../Scripts/on-off_button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No that's not the problem, besides I thought that I should never put static Urls like this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

use this maybe solve:

```
function switchOnOff() {
$("a .bt_off").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("bt_on");
});
$("a .bt_on").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("bt_off");
});
```

}​
or

```
function switchOnOff() {
$('.bt_off').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("bt_on");
});
$('bt_on').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("bt_off");
});
```

}​